# HTTP keep-alive with TCP in Go

Tags: http, go, tcp, keep-alive

I'm trying TCP in Go and trying to make an HTTP call from a TCP client to another HTTP server.

I run another HTTP server locally.

I noticed that whenever the header `connection: close` is present in the request, the TCP client can read the whole response from the HTTP server.
However, when the header `connection: close` is not present in the request, only the header part is read from the connection. The body is not read even though the HTTP server returns a body.

Here is the client code

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {

    con, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer con.Close()

    serverReader := bufio.NewScanner(con)

    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    buf.WriteString("GET / HTTP/1.1\n")
    buf.WriteString("Content-Type: text/hmtl\n")
    //buf.WriteString("Connection: close\n")
    buf.WriteString("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.134 Safari/537.36\n")
    buf.WriteString("Accept: */*\n")
    buf.WriteString("Host: 127.0.0.1\n")
    buf.WriteString("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\n\n")

    if _, err = con.Write(buf.Bytes()); err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to send the client request: %v\n", err)
    }

    //Waiting for the server response
    for serverReader.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(serverReader.Text())
    }

}
```

server code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var handler http.HandlerFunc = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println("request received")

        if r.URL.String() == "/path" {
            w.WriteHeader(400)
            return
        }
        w.WriteHeader(200)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write([]byte("hello"))
        w.Write([]byte("hi"))
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
        w.Write([]byte("how're you"))
        return
    }
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)
}
```

Could you help me with reading the response body ven

Comment: I recommend that you make yourself familiar with the HTTP protocol and what HTTP keep-alive means. It means that the peer keeps the connection open after the request+response is done, which means that one cannot just attempt to read as much as possible to get the full HTTP message. Instead one need to read the HTTP header, find out Content-Length (or chunked Transfer-Encoding) and read as much as defined in the header or by chunked encoding.

Comment: I'd also note that the server is not required to keep connection alive even if the client has asked for it; and also it is not required to honor the timeout value the client asked for, if any. The `Connection` header field is just an appeal, not a requirement. So, what Steffen said: the client _must_ obey what is communicated by the server in the `Content-Length` field of the header of its response.